# Close the Drawer on Tap ListTile

Tags: flutter, dart, drawer

Want that onTap ListTile of Drawer,drawer closed.

I have used Navigation.pop(context) but it pop whole screen.
I have a CustomScaffold with global key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put this code in any onpressed event and you will get a solution.

```
onPressed: () {
      if (_scaffoldKey.currentState.isDrawerOpen)
        _scaffoldKey.currentState.openEndDrawer();
      else {
        _scaffoldKey.currentState.openDrawer();
      }
    },
```